# Error with the function bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_vert_add() in blender

Tags: python, blender

I come across the function `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_vert_add()` in some GitHub scripts but when I type in this function in the console, the following error pops up:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<blender_console>", line 1,
 in <module>   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender
 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
     ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw) AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_vert_add" error, could not be found
```

Actually this error occurs for all the 2.7x and 2.8x version I used. Could you kindly offer some idea?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I installed some in-package add-ons and the option "add single vertex" appeared.

Regards

Comment: I am left wonder what packages are those? Is there an addon with this I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

To use that function, you need the "Add Mesh: Extra Objects" add-on to be enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).